# Can I use information of a dict key to define another key of the same dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

What I'd like to do is the following:

```
test_dict = dict(value = 1,
                 property = properties_list[value-1]
                )
```

Naturally, I couldn't do it this way, since it throws me an error saying that name 'value' is not defined.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: The question is a little hard to follow. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Declare `value = 1` before and then do `test_dict = dict(value=value, property =properties_list[value-1])`. Is there any problem with that?

Comment: I have a previously defined list (e.g. properties_list) from which I extract the value of the 'property' key of the dict. But the selected item of the properties_list depend on the 'value' key of the dict. Is it clearer?

Comment: @Countour-Integral I don't see a problem with that, I'd just like to know if there's a way to do it without having to create another variable outside the dict

Comment: you need to be sure all your keys are int and not string , or am I wrong

Comment: test_dict[value] - 1 ?? no its the key value not the key

Comment: @pippo1980 that doesn't work, since the test_dict is not yet defined

Comment: But since `value = 1`, did you mean: `property = properties_list[0]`?

Comment: @quamrana yes, that's why I subtract 1 from ```value```.

Comment: So you meant: `dict(value = 1, property = properties_list[0])`?

Comment: I am at loss , do you want your property value to be the 'value key' [value -1] or  'value key' -1 ?? , just change name to your first dict_test key to be clearer, (I know dictionary dont have first items, I meant first in your code)

Comment: I am bookmarking this

Comment: Python-3.8: `dict(value=(x := calc()), property=properties_list[x - 1])`.

Comment: The ```property``` will be chosen on the ```properties_list``` accordingly to the ```value```. So if ```value = 1``` then ```property = properties_list[0]```, if ```value = 2``` then ```property = properties_list[1]``` and so on

Comment: @GabrielDante no, there is no other way if you want to define it all in one go.

Comment: @ekhumoro well, that creates a variable too.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So would creating an entry in the dict. The value has to go *somewhere*, right?

Comment: [What do I do when I need a self referential dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3738381/984421).

Comment: @ekhumoro um, no, creating an entry in the dict does not create a variable? I'm not sure how you figure that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Because the dict is a variable (i.e. like `test_dict` in the answer below).

Comment: @ekhumoro right, but it doesn't create *an additional variable* which the OP says they are trying to avoid. So there is on variable, `test_dict`, with your solution, there are two, `test_dict` and `x`, which is how I've interpreted the OP's comments as trying to avoid

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga This is getting silly, but if you must: `x = dict(value=(x := calc()), property=properties_list[x - 1])`. Now there's only one variable ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by using an [assignment expression](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) (aka “the walrus operator”) which were introduced in Python 3.8.

```
properties_list = [42, 13]

test_dict = dict(value=(_:=1), property=properties_list[_-1])

print(test_dict)  # -> {'value': 1, 'property': 42}
```

Comment: Note that this creates a new variable `value`.

Comment: @Countour-Integral: So what?

Comment: @martineau the OP seems to want to avoid that, although it isn't completely clear

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Then they should mention it in their question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can add keys after the dictionary is defined you could do

```py
test_dict = dict(value = 1)
test_dict['property'] = properties_list[test_dict['value']-1]
```